# How do I upgrade the version of phpMyAdmin from 3.3 to 3.5?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've installed phpMyAdmin and I want to change its theme, I want to install the Metro 2.0 theme from http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/themes.php, but this theme is only compatible with the version 3.5 of phpMyAdmin, while my current version is: `3.3.2deb1`.

How can I upgrade this version to 3.5?

I tried to reinstall the `phpmyadmin` package and then install it using the `apt-get install phpmyadmin` command, but it's always the version `3.3.2deb1` being installed.

Comment: See [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](http://askubuntu.com/q/151283/88802) for the "why".

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you running? Only 10.04 still has 3.3.x version of phpMyAdmin. The latest stable 13.04 [includes](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=raring&searchon=names&keywords=phpmyadmin) a 3.5.8 version.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I guess you need to add their ppa to your system, but in this case you'll get latest version, which is 4.0 for most ubuntu releases, and 3.5 for oneiric

ppa home:

https://launchpad.net/~nijel/+archive/phpmyadmin

terminal commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nijel/phpmyadmin;
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin;
```

graphical way:

Open Update manager / Settings / Other Software / Add / "ppa:nijel/phpmyadmin"
click ok and provide password when needed, then:
in Update manager click Chek and you're ready to update phpmyadmin :)

*upgrading using ppa, is recomended

*adding ppa is one time operation

Comment: Too lazy to try this suggestion? Try it, it works.