# How to upgrade PHPmyAdmin

Tags: apt, phpmyadmin

I installed PHPmyAdmin through this code

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin apache2-utils
```

I want to know how to upgrade through terminal

Comment: See [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/304827/91046) answer

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade phpmyadmin only use

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

This `install` with an already installed package will upgrade it to the latest version.

To upgrade all packages — phpmyadmin and all others — use

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: latest version which the distribution supports, not necessarily the latest version of phpMyAdmin.