# How to upgrade phpmyadmin to version 4.9.4?

Tags: phpmyadmin

My phpmyadmin says: A new version of phpMyAdmin is available and you should consider updating it. The most recent version is 4.9.4, released on 2020-01-08.

I followed this guide [How to upgrade PHPmyAdmin [revisited]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947805/how-to-upgrade-phpmyadmin-revisited), and now it says: Version information: 4.9.1deb2, latest stable version: 4.9.4

What do I have to do to get 4.9.4?

My server is Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Depends upon how you originally installed PHPmyAdmin. 4.9.2 is the newest available deb  package in either Debian or Ubuntu repositories. PPAs and other third-party sites may have something different.

Comment: The PPA needs to be updated https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15236#issuecomment-569642409
I will try to free some time to do the update

Comment: Please accept the response :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15515#issuecomment-589945384

I published the 4.9.4 version to the Ubuntu PPA.

Available for Eoan and Bionic only.