# Can't update Ubuntu server 16.04 to 18.04 due to missing phpMyAdmin PPA

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, apt, ppa, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to install the latest updates for 16.04 so I can upgrade to 18.04. I'm getting errors with the phpMyAdmin PPA, which I understand is due to the fact that [the original package maintainer (nijel) has deleted the PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/1176573/475173).

```
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nijel/phpmyadmin/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nijel/phpmyadmin/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nijel/phpmyadmin/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nijel/phpmyadmin/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/phpmyadmin/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/phpmyadmin/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/phpmyadmin/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/phpmyadmin/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Err:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nijel/phpmyadmin/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nijel/phpmyadmin/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Fetched 2,313 kB in 4s (486 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nijel/phpmyadmin/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/phpmyadmin/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/phpmyadmin/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nijel/phpmyadmin/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

So I tried to remove the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:nijel/phpmyadmin
```

But this didn't work:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~nijel/ubuntu/phpmyadmin'.
The user named '~nijel' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/phpmyadmin'
Please choose from the following available PPAs:
```

I also tried this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.
sudo apt install phpmyadmin
```

But I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
phpmyadmin is already the newest version (4:4.6.6-1+deb.cihar.com~xenial.2).
```

How do I resolve this so I can run the upgrade to 18.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove PPAs from the system by

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*nijel*.list ~/
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:phpmyadmin/ppa
```

and then revert `phpmyadmin` package to [the version from official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=phpmyadmin):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall phpmyadmin=4:4.5.4.1-2ubuntu2.1
```

Then run `sudo apt-get update` to ensure that errors gone and next run `sudo do-release-upgrade` .

Comment: I'm still getting the same errors on update, due to the `E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nijel/phpmyadmin/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages`. Do I need to remove this PPA? How do I do that?

Comment: Then remove this PPA from the system by hard way `sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*nijel*.list ~`  and run `sudo apt-get update` again.

Comment: Yep, thanks. I found that info somewhere and manually removed them just before you replied. Thanks for your help.